# Error de importación matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

tengo un GUI en mi pc, al momento de cambiar de pc e intentar correr el archivo, me salta el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\aaa\Documents\Proyecto G2\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>  
    from matplotlib import _api, animation, cbook
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 34, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

En VS code no me marca ningún error y en mi pc puedo ejecutarlo normal

Comment: Verifica que las versiones sean iguales y que el nombre esté bien escrito

Comment: ¿Has instalado las dependencias correspondientes a tu script antes de correr al código? Recuerda que antes de ejecutar un script tienes que asegurarte de que el equipo en el que lo harás tiene las dependencias/librerías necesarias para ello, en este caso, que tenga instalado matplotlib.

Comment: `pip install Pillow`

Comment: Hola, ya instalé matplotlib y no funciona, al momento de instalar matplotlib instala numpy y pillow automáticamente. Intente desinstalando y volviendo a instalar y sigue igual

Comment: Verifica que el entorno con el que instalas las dependencias sea el mismo que el que usas para ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar lo siguiente, para reinstalar `matplotlib`:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

Además, también es posible que falle `PIL`, para esto, reinstalar `pillow`:

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
```

Otra alternativa es usar *Process Monitor*, y ver qué archivos *DLL* está leyendo python.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Una vez identificado el nombre del `dll`, volverlo a descargar desde internet, guardar una copia del archivo antes de reemplazarlo.

Comment: Lo instalé al inicio y no funciona, lo intente desinstalando así pip uninstall matplotlib y volviendo a instalar, y sigue mal

Comment: @lotsoeloso Edité la respuesta.